# Disabling all kendoui elements from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a legacy ASP.NET application. We started to rewrite its UI to Kendo UI, but so far it still uses traditional ASP.NET server controls, and we are using Kendo UI just to style the UI.

The page is sort of a portal, with a lot of user controls, loaded dynamically, based on application context.

One bit of functionality we need is to disable all controls on a page (to show the page read-only). This works for parts of the page that weren't rewritten yet (which use the old ASP.NET server controls) but doesn't for new modules which use Kendo UI.

Is there any way to find all Kendo UI controls on the page and disable them all?

Thanks.

Comment: Will you have to re-enable them after?

Comment: Do you have the kendo controls created on javascript or are they created server side using the ASP Extension methods?

Comment: No. The disable is done only once, in page load (called from a window.addEvent('domready',...) event

Comment: what kind of kendo controls you are using in the page?

Comment: The controls are created using markup only, adding class='k-textbox' for textboxes, and attribute data-role="dropdownlist", data-role="datepicker" and data-role="numerictextbox"

Comment: To clarify: No, I don't need to re-enable them. The disable is done only once, in page load (called from a window.addEvent('domready',...) event. When we'll finish all rewrite we'll move to pure client ui w/ mvvm and use data-bind for enable/disable, but for now I just need a "quick and dirty" disable all. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if theres a specific piece of code that will disable all controls at once. I would just try to group them all in a class or two if you could and just disable them that way.  `$(".KendoControls").attr("readonly", "readonly");`

Comment: You should just find all input fields and disable them.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that will search for various controls of kendo and disable them. Please see below as an example to disable all dropdownlist in a page:

```
function DisableAll() { 
// disable all DropDowns
$(".k-list-container").each(function () {
    var elementId = this.id.split("-")[0];
    var tempDL = $("#"+elementId).data("kendoDropDownList");
    tempDL.enable(false);
});
```

}

Similarly you can write for all other controls or only those kendo controls that you are using within the page